# AngularJS : get list of objects from service in the controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, get, promise, deferred-loading

I have this service to retrieve a list of cars from a WebAPI server :

```js
    angular.module('MyServices')
    .service('carService', ['$http', '$rootScope', 
        function ($http, $rootScope) {

        this.getList =function(userName, ticket)
        {
            $rootScope.$emit('My.OnBusy');

            $http.get('api/car'
               , { params: {userName: userName} }
           ).success(function (data) {
                $rootScope.$emit('My.OnIdle');

                if (data[0] && data[0].Name == "Error")
                {
                    $rootScope.$emit("My.OnError", data[0].Model);
                    return {};
                }

                return data;
           }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $rootScope.$emit('My.OnIdle');
               $rootScope.$emit("My.OnError", "Error in communication with server.");
               return {};
           });
        }
    }]
    );
```

And in the controller I use it like this :

```js
angular.module('MyControllers')
.controller('carController', function CarController($rootScope, $scope, $http, carService) {

    $scope.loadCars = function (userName, ticket) {
        $scope.Cars = carService.getList(userName, ticket);
    }

    $scope.loadCars($rootScope.user.email, '');
});
```

But the **$scope.Cars** is Undefined after the cal to **getList**. I tried to use **"then"** when I call the service but it was unsuccessful.

Saying that I want to handle success and error of the operation in the service itself, how can I get final result in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference :

Service should be like this :

```js
  angular.module('MyServices')
    .service('carService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q'
        function ($http, $rootScope, $q) {

        this.getList =function(userName, ticket)
        {
            $rootScope.$emit('My.OnBusy');

            var deferred = $q.defer();


            $http.get('api/car'
               , { params: {userName: userName} }
           ).success(function (data) {
                $rootScope.$emit('My.OnIdle');

                if (data[0] && data[0].Name == "Error")
                {
                    $rootScope.$emit("My.OnError", data[0].Model);
                    deferred.reject(data[0].Address);
                    //return {};
                }

                deferred.resolve(data);
                //return data;
           }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               $rootScope.$emit('My.OnIdle');
               $rootScope.$emit("My.OnError", "Error in communication with server.");
               deferred.reject("Error in communication with server.");                   
               //return {};
           });

           return deferred.promise;

        }
    }]
    );
```

And now **"then"** works in the controller :

```js
angular.module('MyControllers')
.controller('carController', function CarController($rootScope, $scope, $http, carService) {

    $scope.loadCars = function (userName, ticket) {
        carService.getList(userName, ticket).then(function (data) {
            $scope.Cars = data;
        });;
    }

    $scope.loadCars($rootScope.user.email, '');
});
```